I am finding hard to understand the trading charges and brokerages. can someone please answer the below queries
I am new to trading a finding it difficult to understand the below. Can anyone please clarify? Thanks in advance
As per the attached screenshot at 12:09 PM today i have cancelled ‘Cover Order’ which i have placed along with the buy order at ‘9:19 AM’. But the ‘Sell’ order status is showing as ‘Complete’ instead of ‘Cancelled’ is this correct?
As per the attached screenshot at 3:15 PM there is buy order with 0 price though i haven’t placed that order it is still popping up. Can any one explain why the order triggered?

Since the ‘Cover Order’ which i cancelled is showing as ‘Complete’ and the Buy order which i haven’t created is triggered for ‘0’ price and the status of it is also complete. The profit and loss got manipulated though i sold for more and bought for less. Is my understanding correct or am i missing anything?

Due to the above-mentioned issues my overall buy and sell got manipulated (See Screenshots) and more ‘brokerage and charges’ deducted from my account. Is my understanding correct or am i missing anything?

Additionally auto square off is charged for the buy order which is triggered for '0' price(not initiated by me system triggered this buy order with 0 price). I see this as looting money. I dont understand if i am wrong or they are wrong.


I found out whats happening with the issues i mentioned above. I  am posting the answer here( issue to issue) as it might help someone who is also facing the same trouble understanding the transactions of intraday.
1.As per the attached screenshot at 12:09 PM today i have cancelled ‘Cover Order’ which i have placed along with the buy order at ‘9:19 AM’. But the ‘Sell’ order status is showing as ‘Complete’ instead of ‘Cancelled’ is this correct? - ANS :We will not be able to modify 'Cover Orders' we will only be able to edit the price in the 'Cover Orders'. So the point here to note is once the 'Cover Order' is created/activated it cannot be 'Cancelled'.

As per the attached screenshot at 3:15 PM there is buy order with 0 price though i haven’t placed that order it is still popping up. Can any one explain why the order triggered? - ANS: The Buy order is triggered as a square off of the short sell order which is created at 12:09 PM

Since the ‘Cover Order’ which i cancelled is showing as ‘Complete’ and the Buy order which i haven’t created is triggered for ‘0’ price and the status of it is also complete. The profit and loss got manipulated though i sold for more and bought for less. Is my understanding correct or am i missing anything? - ANS: My understanding is not correct. The 'Cover Order' once created cannot be cancelled hence the cover order of sell is executed and showing as 'complete' which is correct. Cover order of 'Sell' is executed with 0 share in hand and hence at the 3:15 auto square off buy is executed though i havent created the buy sytem auto squared off( which is system bough share behalf of me


4.Due to the above-mentioned issues my overall buy and sell got manipulated (See Screenshots) and more ‘brokerage and charges’ deducted from my account. Is my understanding correct or am i missing anything? - ANS: Yes, the missing understanding is explained in ANS 3
5.Additionally auto square off is charged for the buy order which is triggered for '0' price(not initiated by me system triggered this buy order with 0 price). I see this as looting money. I dont understand if i am wrong or they are wrong. - ANS: I am wrong here, Please look at the ANS 3 for explanation
